# How to wrap junit @Test method to be able to restart tests by pop from stack

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In a normal @Test method in junit (4.11) the method is invoked with reflection and it happens (often or everytime) that the frame below the invokation of the @Test method is a native frame. The fact that those native frames can't be popped in JPDA (as far as I understood) prevents unit test methods from being restarted very quickly in the debugger (e.g. if you encountered that a variable is involved in the bug you're searching which you didn't watch in the previous run). Is there any way to get around this with included features in junit or JRE (I guess possible solutions might be to prevent usage of native frames or tell junit to wrap the calls in a poppable frame). I'm aware that I could implement that myself with one method wrapper, but I'm looking for included, more elegant features.